# How to center all child elements with float left property

Tags: css

I was unable to find any solution to my problem. I don't want any space between child elements so i have added float:left to child elements. But it is causing problem when elements breaks into 2 lines.[image: Expected Output]

[image: Issue]

HTML :

```
<span class="section-title">
    <span class="yellow">This</span>
    <span class="red">is</span>
    <span class="brown">test</span>
    <span class="">content</span>
</span>
```

CSS :

```
.section-title {text-align:center;}
.section-title span {float: left; display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Added in my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the unwanted space, don't `float: left;`, but set `font-size: 0;` on the parent element, re-setting it on the children to the `font-size` you want.

Also, you used a `span` for the container which by default has `display: inline;`. Here, you want an element that has `display: block;`. With `display: inline;` the text-centering cannot work.

So **either** set `display: block;` on the `span` **or** use a `div` instead of a `span`. `div` has `display: block;` by default. I'd recommend the latter, but I'm not sure whether you have control over the HTML, so I did not change it.

```css
.section-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
}
.section-title span {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.brown {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<span class="section-title">
  <span class="yellow">This</span>
  <span class="red">is</span>
  <span class="brown">test</span>
  <span>content</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
.section-title {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
 }

 .section-title span {
     font-size: 36px;
     display: inline-block;
     text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```